# Special characters in devbridge autocomplete

Tags: php, json, ajax, autocomplete

I am using the latest devbridge autocomplete, which shows German cities from a mysql database, but it will not reurn special characters.

My test file looks like:

```
<html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<style>
    h1 {text-align: center; margin: 20px 20px;}
    #autocomplete,#country {margin: 0 auto;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Autocomplete Input</h1>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">

<script>
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'search.php',
    minChars: 2,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The search.php file looks like:

```
<?php

///
/*** connect to your DB here ***/
include_once "scripts/connect_all.php";
///

//retrieve the search term and strip and clean input
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['query'])); 

//try to make user input safer
$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($myConnection, $term);

//build a query on the database
$sqlCommand = "SELECT gemeinde FROM cities WHERE gemeinde LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 

//query the database for entries containing the term
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

$reply = array();
$reply['suggestions'] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $gemeinde = $row["gemeinde"];
    $reply['suggestions'][]=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['gemeinde']));

} 
mysqli_free_result($query);

//format the array into json data
echo json_encode($reply);

?>
```

When running `search.php?query=münch` it will throw out:

```
{"suggestions":["Münchehofe","Müncheberg, Stadt","Münchenbernsdorf, Stadt","Korntal-Münchingen, Stadt","Münchwald","München, Landeshauptstadt","Grafing b.München, St","Garching b.München, St","Kirchheim b.München","Gdefr. Geb. (Lkr München)","Münchsmünster","Bodenwerder, Münchhausenstadt","Münchweiler an der Alsenz","Glan-Münchweiler","Münchweiler am Klingbach","Münchweiler an der Rodalb","Waldmünchen, St","Münchberg, St","Münchhausen","Münchsteinach","Schwabmünchen, St"]}
```

But when feeding this to the autocomplete function it will throw out a list with correct places, but convert the special characters like `ü` into `&uuml`;

- `M&uuml;nchehofe`
- `M&uuml;ncheberg`
- `M&uuml;nchenbernsdorf`
- etc

How can I make sure the special characters are remained in the output of the autocomplete function?

Answer (score 0):

Got it and shared the answer below for future references. Removing the htmlentities and stripslashes did the job, so:

```
$reply['suggestions'][]=($row['gemeinde']);
```